# Where is yearMonthDuration defined?

Tags: xml, types

XML has a datatype called `yearMonthDuration`. Or at least I thought so.

If I look at the list of XML datatypes [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes), I cannot see it. All there is is something called a `duration`.

If I look further down I can see there is a [section on duration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#adding-durations-to-dateTimes).

Nowhere can I find mention of yearMonthDuration. If I google it, it takes me to a [third party website](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_yearMonthDuration.html) (non W3C) with its definition. The second Google link points to w3c's website on a separate standard, XForms.

Why isn't it in the core XML spec? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xs:yearMonthDuration` was first defined in the XPath 2.0 specification (and associated specs such as XQuery 1.0 and XSLT 2.0). It was then moved over to become a standard XSD built-in type, and the definitive specification for XPath 3.0 is by reference to its definition in XSD 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I finally did find that it's defined in the [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#dt-yearMonthDuration) as follows:

> [Definition] xs:yearMonthDuration is derived from xs:duration by
>   restricting its lexical representation to contain only the year and
>   month components. The value space of xs:yearMonthDuration is the set
>   of xs:integer month values. The year and month components of
>   xs:yearMonthDuration correspond to the Gregorian year and month
>   components defined in section 5.5.3.2 of [ISO 8601], respectively.